# Get the function fitting my datapoints in R

Tags: r

I want to get the function for the line fitting my datapoints:

```
x <- c(200,100,50,25,12.50,6.25,3.13,0.00)
y <- c(0.6365, 0.315, 0.157, 0.083,0.048, 0.037,0.0325, 0.0165)

plot(x,y)    
lines(lowess(x,y), col="blue")
```

Comment: You can get lots of mileage out of `str`. Partial answer here: http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg77935.html

Comment: `lowess` doesn't generate a closed form function. You might consider using `loess` instead which allows you to predict into new `x` values.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm used by `lowess` and `loess` does not create a single, simple function, rather it fits a new regression for every possible point that you could predict at, so it is in essence an infinity of functions (though in practice it will only compute those that you actually use).  You can see the `loess.demo` function in the TeachingDemos package to interactively explore what is happening.

The `loess` function does have an option for fitting a spline to the results of the loess algorithm, so technically you could "get" that function, but it is not easily interpretable.

What do you want to do with the results?  If you just want to predict in R, then use `loess` as mentioned in the comments and give it the values where you want to predict at.  If you want to implement the function outside of R then it may be simplest (and sufficient) to generate predictions from `loess` at a multitude of x values, then load those into your outside program along with some form of interpolation.  If you just want to explore the relationship then the plot is probably your best option.

Comment: It is a standard curve, which I want to use for calculation of my measurements.